# Css Flexbox data list with header

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this kind of implementation (here is not mine but look the same). So each row is a `display:flex` I can't realy use a `table` because each line is a link and also have space between `table tr` with border radius and box-shadow is a pain. So I went with flebox.
[image]

But now I need to add labels on top of each `column` (yes like in a table header). So my question is, what is your best approach to doing so and be sure to keep my labels aligns with the content of each row ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

put the container in flexbox with flex-direction: column and put your header in flex-direction: row and justify-content: space-between